# LIKE operator is not fetching results in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-like

I want to get the results by applying `LIKE` operator. But its not giving me the result.

Below is my Query.

`Select * from TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO where upper(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE '%ami%';`

The above query is not fetching me any results from the data below

Query in procedure

```
Select * from TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO where upper(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE '%' || upper(P_ZONENAME) || '%';
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match it with UPPER CASE.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO
WHERE
    UPPER(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE upper('%Ami%'); -- used upper case AMI here
```

Cheers!!

Comment: what if its like this `'%Ami%'` ??

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check now

Answer (score 2):

`upper(ZONE_HEAD_NAME)` is all uppercase, so it will never be `LIKE '%ami%'` (which is all lowercase).

Comment: what if its like this `'%Ami%'` ??

Comment: `upper('rami')` is `'RAMI'`, so that won't match `%Ami%` either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LOWER` not `UPPER`:

```sql
Select * from TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO where LOWER(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE '%ami%';
```

or use upper case in the `LIKE`:

```sql
Select * from TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO where UPPER(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE '%AMI%';
```

or wrap both sides of the `LIKE` in the same case-transforming function:

```sql
Select * from TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO where UPPER(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%Ami%');
```

Comment: what if its like this `'%Ami%'` ??

Comment: @BN Updated with a method that should work for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Select * from TBL_ZONAL_HEAD_INFO where upper(ZONE_HEAD_NAME) LIKE upper('%ami%');
```

You have used upper for ZONE_HEAD_NAME and used `'%ami%'` which won't ever return any records, ever.
So, either make both in upper() function, or just use Uppercase for select query here, like `'%AMI%'`.